# How to do this question using complex numbers and without using differentiation?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

$A(1,-3), B(4,3)$ are two points on the curve $y = x - \frac 4x$. The points on the curve, the tangents at which are parallel to chord $AB$ are?
The answer to the question is $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0)$.
It's very easy to do this by equating slope of curve to slope of AB, But I tried it with complex numbers and without using calculus, but ended up with weird results. Does anyone knows a way?

Comment: How do you define a tangent line without using calculus?

Comment: You just need a point on the line and the slope of that line to define a straight line. Defining a tangent to the curve at some point when we don't know the slope at that point, without using calculus sounds tricky you're right.

Comment: Using calculus, do you agree that it amounts to solve $f'(x)$= slope of $AB$, i.e., $1+\frac{4}{x^2}=2$ giving **at once** $x=-2$ and $x=2$. I don't see how complex numbers would be of any use...

Answer (score 2):

You told not to use differentiation. Okay but I won't be using complex number either because I don't know what to do with complex numbers. For this perticular question, let $y=mx+c$ be that tangent line. Clearly $m=2$. Let's find the solution of this line and the curve.
$$2x+c=x-\dfrac 4x$$ $$\implies x^2+cx+4=0 \tag{ 1}$$
Now as the line is a tangent to the given curve then we will get only one solution of this equation $$\implies D=0 
 \implies c=\pm4 $$ putting these values one by one in eq$^n$ (1) we get $$x_1=2 \qquad x_2=-2$$ the tangents are $$L_1\equiv y=2x+4\\L_2\equiv y=2x-4$$

Comment: [+1] But instead of "If this line is a tangent then we will get" you should write "this line is a tangent if and only if..."

Comment: Tried for the betterment of language. Edited it